# How to compare SSL certificates using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, security, ssl, https, afnetworking

In my iPhone app I'm using an `https` connection with a self-signed `SSL` certificate to download sensible data (username and password) from a server.

This app is for private use only, it is not meant for production.

I'm using `AFNetworking` to manage the `https` connection but, since my certificate isn't signed from a CA, in order to make it work I had to add the following to the header of the `AFURLConnectionOperation` class:

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1
```

But with this my app will allow any certificate.

Is there a way to allow only the certificate from my server maybe bundling it in the app and comparing it with the certificate provided by the server in the https connection?
And if it were possible, would there be any significant advantage in terms of security?

I'm very new to security and I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *SSL Pinning*, where the app verifies that a known certificate or public key matches one presented by a remote server.

AFNetworking supports both pinning with certificates or public keys. You'll need to add the certificate(s) or public key(s) to your app's Bundle, and enable the feature by setting either the [`defaultSSLPinningMode`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/776c879c9d3cd20b9a3c15490666e8ab6d1f2bf1/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h#L144) property on AFHttpClient or the [`SSLPinningMode`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/776c879c9d3cd20b9a3c15490666e8ab6d1f2bf1/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h#L178) property on `AFURLConnectionOperation`.

You can pin using `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` or `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate`. `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate` means that the server's certificate must exactly match one of those in the bundle.

`AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` is more liberal and means that the server's certificate must match for any public key in the bundle, or any public key attached to certificates in the bundle.

There's an [example of setting the pinning mode](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/f51f0b8533e1e5d549ef718eed60f7637f249d41/Example/Classes/Networking%20Extensions/AFAppDotNetAPIClient.m#L34) in the AppDotNet example.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Are there any significant security advantages doing this?

Comment: SSL Pinning offers additional protection from MITM attacks and compromised CAs. There's some insight [here](http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2012/04/why-app-developers-should-care-about.html).

Comment: Just what I was looking for! One last question, do I need to somehow set the certificate file against which the AFNetworking Library should compare the certificate provided by the server or the library will find it on its own?

Comment: AFNetworking will automatically find certificates in the bundle root.

Comment: My certificate has .crt extension not .cer and when I try to connect the following error is logged in xcode:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7157d40` the header file says that the certificate should be .cer may this be the problem?

Comment: I think you'll need to convert the certificate to the right format but I don't know the best way offhand

Comment: convert `.crt file` to `.cer file`:  Open terminal and run the following command.

`openssl x509 -in www.mydomain.com.crt -out www.mydomain.com.cer -outform der`

Answer (score 8):

To expand a bit on David's answer with respect to `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` versus `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate`. Ideally, you would pin the public key and not the certificate. That's because some sites and services, like Google, rotate their certificates every 30 days or so. But they re-certify the same public key.

The certificates are rotated frequently to keep the size of the CRL small for mobile clients. But they re-certify the same public key (rather than creating a new one) to allow for key continuity testing.

Public key pinning is why tools like [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) miss the mark. The certificate is expected to change; the public key is not.

Public key pinning is a lot like SSH's `StrictHostKeyChecking`, if you are familiar with it.

OWASP has a write-up on it too at [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).