# Custom Trust Store with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, certificate, afnetworking, truststore

I'm developing some iOS apps and I'm downloading/uploading data which are very sensitive.
I'm using AFNetworking to do that requests and my question is simple:
I reach only 3 different certificates in all the app, can I custom AFNetworking's layer to accept only these 3 certificates?

The aim of this manipulation will be to avoid "Man To the Middle" attacks and so avoid injection and/or retrieval of any additional information during the HTTP exchanges.

Comment: In general, we expect questions on Stack Overflow to be based on actual practical problems. What have you tried so far, and why hasn't it worked?

Comment: thank you for your reply, and yes i know in general SO is a forum based on questions. I have tried nothing because there is no forum/help section for this very known library on iOS, precisely based on challenge/ssl/certificate questions. And I know that my question is very precise (and so not useful for everyone) that's why I prefer to post on SO

Answer (score 0):

All AFNetworking operations inherit from AFURLConnectionOperation, which defines a block called `authenticationChallenge`.  Setting this block on your operations will define how AFNetworking responds to the NSURLConnectionDelegate method `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`.  Specifically, you will want to inspect `challenge.proposedCredential`.

If you don't want to set this block on every operation, you could also subclass the operation type you're using (like AFJSONRequestOperation, for example), and override `connection:
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` with the behavior you want.

Comment: @JulienG There's a much simpler way to do this with AFNetworking itself rather than dropping down and overriding NSURLConnection methods. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605898/how-to-compare-ssl-certificates-using-afnetworking/16606296#16606296). Basically, you add the certificates to your app bundle and set the defaultSSLPinningMode on your AFHttpClient. I can expand this to an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: You should use @DavidCaunt's suggestion.  I incorrectly thought SSLPinning limited the restriction to 1 certificate.

Comment: Yes it's much more clear. Expend it and i'll give you the check box :)