# SSL Pinning with AFNetworking 1.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

Im new to the AFNetworking framework and the SSL Pinning.
I already did the :

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ = 1
```

but dont think its enough, its correct?
How can i do this?
Heres my current request :

```
NSArray *info = @{@"action" : @"test"}; 
NSError * error = nil; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSMutableURLRequest*request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]; 
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data]; 
[body appendData:jsonData]; 
[request setHTTPBody:body]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:request.URL];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation
*operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *error;

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response String %@",responseString); 
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)  {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription); }]; 
[operation start];
```

The request works just fine, but i dont know if its really pinning the ssl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare SSL certificates using AFNetworking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605898/how-to-compare-ssl-certificates-using-afnetworking)

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking are you using? Older versions used the `#define`, and newer use properties on the `AFHTTPClient` or operation

Comment: AFNetworking 1, the older one with the define.
I think i got it working, but how can i check if its pinning correctly? @DavidCaunt

Comment: Yeah...but what version specifically? 1.? You can check if it is working by connecting to `https://httpbin.org/get` or similar and the connection should fail with error -1012

Comment: I think i got it work, o didnt get any errors. Thanks @DavidCaunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set  `SSLPinningMode` property to `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate` befor calling start on  `AFJSONRequestOperation`.