# What's the difference of the 3 AFNetwork SSL modes: AFSSLPinningModeNone, AFSSLPinningModePublicKey and AFSSLPinningModeCertificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, afnetworking

I tried the AFNetwork 2.0 iOS example, but can't understand the 3 AFNetwork SSL modes: AFSSLPinningModeNone, AFSSLPinningModePublicKey and AFSSLPinningModeCertificate.

```
    _sharedClient = [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
    _sharedClient.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
```

As my understanding, 'SSL Pinning' is to compare the certificates fetched from the server to the ones bundled in the root directory of the projects. If they are the same, then 'pinning successful', otherwise failed.

But whey there are 3 modes, what's the difference? and why the official example worked when the SSL security was set to AFSSLPinningModeNone but NOT work when AFSSLPinningModePublicKey and AFSSLPinningModeCertificate.

Forgive me to ask such a fundamental question here, but I found no document and the codes need more time for me to understand.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16605898/372643)? (If so, let me know, I'll close it as a duplicate.)

Comment: Yes, it's duplicated. thanks for the information.