# AFNetworking checking server certificate domain

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have a static function which I use to retrieve a configuration file through AFNetworking library, as follows:

```
static func getConfiguration(success: NetworkServiceSuccessBlock, failure: NetworkServiceFailureBlock) -> AFHTTPSessionManager? {

    let sessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    sessionManager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

    sessionManager.GET(getConfigurationUrl()!, parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: success, failure: failure)

    return sessionManager
}
```

I need to check the server SSL certificate domain to be the proper one, something like challenge.protectionSpace.host for NSURLSession, and I need the check to determine whether the GET request will fail or not.

**EDIT:** I don't want to perform SSL Pinning with certificates stored in the app bundle, it is enough for me to verify the server certificate domain is correct.

Can someone point me in the right direction to perform this?

Comment: It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605898/how-to-compare-ssl-certificates-using-afnetworking.

Also have a look on their github.

Comment: Thank you @Murloc but I need only to verify the certificate server domain, not to compare it with another one stored in the app bundle, that is why I specified challenge.protectionSpace.host property to give the idea of what I am looking for.